# Expo says react-native is missing

Tags: react-native

I installed expo using the facebook guide by running

```
    npm install -g expo-cli
    npm install react-navigation
    expo start
```

However it still says

```
npm WARN @react-native-community/netinfo@2.0.10 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.57 <0.60 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/googlemaps@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/markerclustererplus@^2.1.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-reanimated@1.0.1 requires a peer of react-native@^0.44.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-webview@5.8.1 requires a peer of react-native@>=0.57 <0.60 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I tried to delete my node_modules folder and rerunning npm install in the directory of my project

It still says react-native not found, although running

```
    react-native -v
```

in command line, shows

```
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native: 0.60.3
```

Comment: What is your `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have only install expo-cli not react native cli , even if your package.json has react-native it is not accessiable from your cli . so you have to install react-native-cli seperately so that you can access react-native.

```
npm install –g react-native-cli
```